# Calling Javascript function multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Simple JavaScript Function:

```
function f1()
{
    alert("HI");
}
```

I'm calling the same Javascript function from two places, say:

```
<input type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="f1()"/>

<input type="submit" id="btn2" onclick="f1()"/>
```

How to find the target element which called this Function?

EDIT: How to check if the element is a button or some other?

Comment: If you're using jquery, what's the point of inline javascript? Use `$(#btn1).click(...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="f1(this)"/>
<input type="submit" id="btn2" onclick="f1(this)"/>
```

Js

```
function f1(el) {
    console.log(el)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Yhvyh/)

Answer (score 2):

```
function f1(element)
{
    alert($(element).attr("id"));

    if ($(element).is(":button")) {
        alert("Im button");
    }
}

<input type="submit" id="btn2" onclick="f1(this)"/>
```

Comment: How to check if the element is a button or some other?

Answer (score 2):

Try with **this**

```
<input type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="f1(this)"/>
<input type="submit" id="btn2" onclick="f1(this)"/>
```

and console like

```
function f1(comp)
{
    console.log(comp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `this` to the function call

`<input type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="f1(this)"/>`

`<input type="submit" id="btn2" onclick="f1(this)"/>`

And modify your js as

```
function f1(el)
{
    alert(el.nodeName) ; // alerts type of HTML element
}
```

`el` will contain a reference to the element

*EDIT* : added code to detect type of HTML element

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
<input type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="f1(this)"/>

<input type="submit" id="btn2" onclick="f1(this)"/>
```

JS:

```
function f1(btn)
{
    alert("Hi from " + btn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you are already** using jquery on your page, maybe you should try giving all the elements that you want to target a shared class and then detect the clicks?

```
<input class="same_kind_buttons" type="submit" id="btn1" />
<input class="same_kind_buttons" type="button" id="btn2" />


<script> 
$(".same_kind_buttons").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("type")); 
  console.log(this.id);
});
</script>
```

Of course if your'e not using jquery on the page you shouldn't include it just for that function and you can use :

```
<input type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="f1(this);"/>
<input type="submit" id="btn2" onclick="f1(this);" />

<script>
  function f1(elem) {
    console.log(elem.tagName);
    console.log(elem.id);
  }
</script>
```